# Which of the following is grammatically sound? "They have/had been doing no work this afternoon"

Tags: sentence-construction, past-perfect

> They have been doing no work this afternoon.

Or

> They had been doing no work this afternoon.

Provided the time specified 'afternoon' elapsed.

Comment: Speaking the same day, you would use _have_. Speaking at a  later date, you would use _had_ with _that_ (or _yesterday) afternoon_.

Comment: I mean it's the same day but the speaker communicates this after the 'afternoon' has passed.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, you would still use _have_.

Comment: If the afternoon is finished, then both sentences are wrong. "*They **did** no work this afternoon*" or less formally, "*They **weren't doing** any work this afternoon.*"

Comment: @KateBunting I agree with you on “have” and “had,” but using the present perfect seems strange to me in this case.  I am not, however, saying the perfect is **necessarily** inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

'They have been doing no work this afternoon.'

As Kate Bunting has commented, the 1st one, as shown above, is appropriate.

Use 'had' only if the events happened on days past.

Comment: In reference to an afternoon in the past, I would expect to see "that" afternoon, rather than "this"afternoon, but I wouldn't declare the use of "this" to be positively erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

I basically agree with gotube.

If it is now evening, the continuous aspect is outright wrong.

> They have done no work this afternoon

is also wrong **unless** the context justifies the perfect aspect. (I cannot easily dream up such a context, but I am unwilling to assert that there is no such context.)

In most contexts, the way to say this is

> They did no work this afternoon

Of course,

> They have been doing no work this afternoon

or

> They have done no work this afternoon

are both correct if it is still afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

**They had been doing no work** this afternoon. [when we arrived at the workshop]

**The past perfect either is preceded or followed by a simple past or past continuous, actual or implied.**

**They had been doing no work** this afternoon when I arrived.

It really is as simple as that.